# Join Two PHP variables to create a button click link

Tags: php, mysql, variables, button, onclick

I have two variables declared one in `cfg.php` and one is being called from mysql.

I need to join these two to create a button click link. I am stuck here :

In `cfg.php` I have

```
$mainurl = "http://training.com/something/"
```

the page I am creating this button link has the include `cfg.php`.

from mysql the userid is called this way:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * from  WHERE City like 'Paris' Limit 0,50";
$query = $db->query($query1) ;

$hotel = mysql_fetch_row($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

my button click code is 
    Select

But the link comes up like this

```
<button onclick="window.location.href =http://training.com/something/106175/overview">Select</button>
```

and the button click does not work.

Any help will be much appreciated.

To Update..... when I Try the below

```
    <button onclick = "window.location.href     =\''.$mainURL.$hotel['userID'].'/overview">Select</button>
```

I get

```
<button onclick="window.location.href ='http://training.com/something/105560/overview">Select</button>
```

Regards,
Jai

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I think I missed when explaining the variables. I have to append two variables to create a url. The first one being the Part of URL itself and the other being the ID followed by /overview. So I will need a URL to be something like [http://training.com]/[UserID]/overview. Following your advise I get the URL Href as follows in the button click href='http://training.com/userid/overview"

Answer (score 1):

You need to encase the URL within its own set of quotes. Modify your PHP such that it outputs something like

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='http://training.com/something/106175/overview'">Select</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

in cfg.php

```
    <?php
    $mainurl = http://training.com/something/
...
    ?>
```

in yourfile.php

```
<?php
include './cfg.php';

...
echo '<input type="button" onclick="window.open(\''.$mainurl.$hotel['EANHotelID'].'\',\'_blank\',\'resizable=yes\')" />';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I think I missed when explaining the variables.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I think I missed when explaining the variables. I have to append two variables to create a url. The first one being the Part of URL itself and the other being the ID followed by /overview. So I will need a URL to be something like [http://training.com]/[UserID]/overview. Following your advise I get the URL Href as follows in the button click href='http://training.com/userid/overview"

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the url in quotes or you can make it a function. Use the code below

```
<script>
function clicking(){
window.location.href='http://training.com/something/106175/overview';
}
</script>
<button onclick="clicking()">Select</button>
```

OR

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='http://training.com/something/106175/overview'">Select</button>
```

Update why you are closing single quote with the double quote. Use the code below

```
<button onclick = "window.location.href     ="$mainURL.$hotel['userID']/overview">Select</button>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Hi I am afraid your code does not work. I need to get the url from variable and the user id from the mysql. This has to be appended by /overview at the end. I did that but the url comes up with missing " in the href. So I know that the button is not working because of missing url encoding. But not sure how i could fix it. hope you can help